# Understanding the Dirac equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, momentum, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am reading a physics book where the Dirac equation is being introduced in the form: $$\left[c \boldsymbol{\alpha} \cdot\left(\boldsymbol{p}+\frac{e \boldsymbol{A}}{c}\right)-e \phi+\beta m c^{2}\right] \Psi=\mathrm{i} \hbar \frac{\partial \Psi}{\partial \mathrm{t}}$$
where $$\boldsymbol{\alpha}_{k}=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
0_{2} & \sigma_{k} \\
\sigma_{k} & 0_{2}
\end{array}\right], \quad \beta=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
\mathbb{I}_{2} & 0_{2} \\
0_{2} & -\mathbb{I}_{2}
\end{array}\right].$$
The author then wants to show the solutions for a constant magnetic field, with $\phi\equiv0$. He then writes:
$$\left[\begin{array}{ll}
m c^{2} & c \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{\pi} \\
c \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{\pi} & -m c^{2}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{l}
\psi_{u} \\
\psi_{l}
\end{array}\right]=E\left[\begin{array}{l}
\psi_{u} \\
\psi_{l}
\end{array}\right]$$
With no explanation anywhere of what $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is, however I can see that it must be connected to $\boldsymbol{p}$.
Next, he states the following equation, with no explanation of where it comes from:
\begin{equation}(\boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{\pi})^{2}=\pi^{2}+i \boldsymbol{\sigma} \cdot \boldsymbol{\pi} \times \boldsymbol{\pi}\tag{*}
\end{equation}
And I do not know why these terms are equal. Can someone explain

1. what is $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ exactly?
2. Where does the result in eq. $(*)$ come from?

Comment: Please state the book title and author.

Comment: It is from _Theoretical Foundations of Electron Spin Resonance_ by John Harriman.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the author wants to find solutions of the form: 
$$
\Psi(t) = e^{-i\frac{1}{\hbar }E \;t}
\begin{pmatrix}
\psi_u \\ \psi_l
\end{pmatrix}
$$
If you insert that and then substitute the values of $\beta$ and $\alpha$ you'll get,
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
I_2 mc^2 & c\sum_k\sigma_k (p_k+ e\frac{A_k}{c}) \\
c\sum_k \sigma_k(p_k+ e\frac{A_k}{c}) & -I_2 mc^2
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_u \\ \psi_l
\end{pmatrix}  = E \begin{pmatrix}
\psi_u \\ \psi_l
\end{pmatrix}
$$
So you've obtained the value of $\mathbf{\pi} =(\textbf{p}+ e\frac{\textbf{A}}{c}) $
.
As for where (*) comes from, it's very straightforward if you know the Pauli matrix identities. In particular:
$$
\sigma_i \sigma_j = 2I\delta_{ij} + i \varepsilon_{ijk}\sigma_k
$$
Apply that to $(\sigma\cdot\pi)^2$ and remember that $(a \times b)_k= \varepsilon_{ijk}a_i b_j$. You will see that you obtain (*)